# Is there a clean way to fill param which may not be needed for hash param in ruby method?

Tags: ruby, parameters, dry

Assuming we have a function, called `mail`, it can receive a `Hash` object, containing from, to, subject, body and so on to send mail, so we often call it like

```
mail(from: 'from@source.com', to: 'to@destination.com', subject: 'hello', body: 'world')
```

but sometimes we needn't supply from address, and this function has a default value, so we will call like this in this situation:

```
mail(to: 'to@destination.com', subject: 'hello', body: 'world')
```

But wait, if we will determine whether we should supply value for `from` depending on the environment, say we have a piece of code like this:

```
if user == me
    mail(to: 'to@destination.com', subject: 'hello', body: 'world')
else
    mail(from: 'from@source.com', to: 'to@destination.com', subject: 'hello', body: 'world')
```

It's not clean, and if we have more than one value, then? So I come to this:

```
params = { subject: 'hello', body: 'world' }
params[:from] = 'from@source.com' unless user == me
params[:to] = 'to@destination.com' unless custom == me
mail(params)
```

So, at last, my question is my title, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-tap). This might be better than PinnyM's solution in cases where you're using `has_key?` to determine whether to assign a default value (rather than just checking whether the hash returns a truthy value for that key):

```
def mail(options={})
  puts "From: " + (options[:from] || "default@source.com")
  puts "To: "   + (options[:to]   || "other@source.com")
  puts "Subject: " + options[:subject]
  puts "Body: " + options[:body]
end

me = "Ajedi32"
user = me
custom = "Other Guy"

mail(
  {
    subject: 'hello',
    body: 'world'
  }.tap { |opts|
    opts[:from] = 'from@source.com' unless user == me
    opts[:to] = 'to@destination.com' unless custom == me
  }
)
```

Output:

```
From: default@source.com
To: to@destination.com
Subject: hello
Body: world
```

I'm not really sure that's much cleaner than your current solution though...

Comment: I think this way may not be more readable, but it's cleaner, so I choose this.

Answer (score 0):

```
mail(
  from: ('from@source.com' unless user == me),
  to: ('to@destination.com' unless custom == me), 
  subject: 'hello', 
  body: 'world' 
)
```

This will result in passing `nil` as the values of the conditional params, should they not be needed.  This should work just fine in most cases, since evaluating a missing key would generally result in `nil` as well.  Should this be a problem for you, you can strip out the `nil` values:

```
params = { ... }.reject{|k,v| v.nil?}
mail params
```